# Closed sets in product topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have an assignment, I have to proof that arbitrary product of close sets is closed in the product topology, I think I have to use complements and treat with opens, what do you think?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use that

$$
\prod_{i \in I} A_i = \bigcap_{i \in I} \pi_i^{-1}(A_i),
$$

where $\pi_i : \prod_j X_j \to X_i, (x_j)_j \mapsto x_i$ is continuous by definition of the product topology.

Why does that help you?

Comment: Oh! then preimages of closed sets are closed!

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\prod_i X_i$ and suppose that $F_i$ is closed in $X_i$. Observe that
$$
(\prod_{i\in I}F_i)^c=\cup_{i\in I}(\prod_{j\in I}G_{i,j}). \tag{*}
$$
Here $G_{i,j}=X_j$ if $j\neq i$ and $G_{i,j}=F_i^c$ if $j=i$. Because $F_i^c$ is open in $X_i$, the definition the product topology implies $\prod_{j\in I}G_{i,j}$ is open in $X$. Since a union of open sets is open, the RHS of (*) is open in $X$. This means $\prod_i F_i$ is closed in $X$.